# iOS Xcode Swift autocomplete broken?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autocomplete

I haven't used Swift that much but coming from Objective C, there's a few things about Swift that's a PITA to get my head around.

In iOS programming, we have `animateWithDuration:` method, which is part of UIView.

So I tried to use Xcode's autocomplete and begin to type:

```
UIView.animateWith
```

The autocomplete shows:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: () -> Void)
```

I then tabbed across to the "duration" field, and then typed in a number:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: () -> Void)
```

Then I tabbed across again to the animation block, and pressed enter like how I normally do it in Objective C, Xcode now shows:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    code
})
```

So then I tabbed one last time to replace "code" with my code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
})
```

That's when Xcode then gives me the error:

> Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type
>   '(FloatLiteralConvertible, animations: () -> Void)'

I don't understand. That's the autocomplete code that Xcode generated for me, why is it giving me an error ?

I noticed if do a simple statement like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    var num = 1 + 1;
})
```

It doesn't give me any errors.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From ["Calling Methods Through Optional Chaining"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_373):

> Any attempt to set a property through optional chaining returns a
>   value of type `Void?`, which enables you to compare against nil to see
>   if the property was set successfully ...

Therefore the type of the expression

```
self.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0)
```

is `Void?` (optional Void). And if a closure consists only of a *single expression*,
then this expression is automatically taken as the *return value*.
The error message is quite misleading, but it comes from the fact that `Void?` is
different from `Void`.

Adding an explicit `return` statement solves the problem:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0)
    return
})
```

**Update:** Adding an explicit `return` statement it not necessary
anymore with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3). From the beta release notes:

> Unannotated single-expression closures with non-Void return types can now be used in Void contexts.