# UIView animateWithDuration Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation

Why this code works:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
                self.blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
                self.blurView?.frame = self.image.frame
                self.addSubview(self.blurView!)
            })
```

And this code does not work

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
            })
```

With following error 
"Cannot invoke animateWithDuration with an argument list of type '(FloatLiteralConvertible, animations: () ->Void)'

Comment: See also [Swift optional chaining doesn't work in closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125328/swift-optional-chaining-doesnt-work-in-closure) or [iOS Xcode Swift autocomplete broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172529/ios-xcode-swift-autocomplete-broken).

Comment: Modifying the code as follows helped

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
                    return Void()
                })