# dispatch_async: Why do I need to return in the block?

Tags: cocoa, swift, return, block, grand-central-dispatch

Maybe it's not specific to Swift, but:

```
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.viewController?.hideProgressHud()
    return
}
```

My `hideProgressHud` method doesn't return anything. declared as

```
func hideProgressHud() {
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.progressHUD?.hide(true)
      self.progressHUD = nil
  }
}
```

Why do I need to `return` in the block? Is there another way to declare it so that I don't need it?

Comment: because When Your Process is completed  then Your value is return

Comment: If its just a ()->() I usually dont write that part at all. Just do {  } and you're good to go.

Comment: You don't need the `return` if `foo()` returns Void. Please post a (small) self-contained example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: your code as you posted it compiles and runs fine without return statement (at least in playground)

Comment: Even after your edit I cannot reproduce the problem ...

Comment: Sorry folks you are right. My problem occurs only with the `hideProgressHud()` being in another ViewController.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. The problem occurs because of the optional chaining in `self.viewController?.hideProgressHud()`. The linked-to "duplicate" should explain that. – Btw, the explicit return is not needed anymore in Swift 1.2, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/27172699/1187415.

Comment: See also [Swift optional chaining doesn't work in closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125328/swift-optional-chaining-doesnt-work-in-closure)

Comment: Thanks @Martin R for that!  I especially love the comment about Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3!